# Vertically center \makebox

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\Fld@bordercolor{0 0 0} % this works.
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|}
     \hline
     S + \makebox(4,1){\TextField[name=textfield,width=3cm,height=0.5cm]{Text}} \\
     \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The input box is shifted upwards. How to center it vertically, so it was on the same line with 'S +'?

Comment: pdftex removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\Fld@bordercolor{0 0 0} % this works.
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|}
     \hline
     \phantom{S}\makebox(4,1){ S+\TextField[name=textfield,width=3cm,height=0.5cm]{Text}} \phantom{S}\\
     \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Notice that `\phantom{S}` is used to get some extra white space before and after the TextField.

---

Here is also a TikZ-based solution: it requires also the `xparse` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{xparse}

% TexTForm: arguments:
% #1 (optional): first letter - default = S
% #2 (optional): text - default = Text
% #3 (mandatory): width (set also the unit, i.e. cm)
% #4 (mandatory): height (set also the unit, i.e. cm)
\NewDocumentCommand{\TexTForm}{O{S} O{Text} m m}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex,show background rectangle]
\node[draw, minimum width=#3, minimum height=#4] (form) {};
\node[left, align=left, yshift=1ex]at (form.south west)(text){#1 + #2};

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\TexTForm{3cm}{0.5cm}\\[2ex]
\TexTForm[T][Other text]{4cm}{0.75cm}\\[2ex]
\TexTForm[Hello][Some other text]{5cm}{1cm}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]